# Join multiple tables on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables (A, B, C), and A has a key shared with B, and B has a key shared with C. I have to combine the three tables to get information from A which is relevant for columns in C. My code is:

```
SELECT
    a.x_code, a.item_id, c.action_type, c.item_name
FROM
    A a
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    B b ON b.item_id = a.item_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    C c ON c.item_name = b.item_name
```

I ran it on MySQL and the query doesn't generate any results and times out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you done an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on your query to see what the query optimizer is doing? That might show you why it's taking a long time.

Comment: hi @jbafford, tried that. It shows that there were zero errors but nothing was executed. No joins or tables created.

Comment: @user5838422: Please also include some sample data from each of your tables in the problem statement, so that it is easier for others to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need outer joins. Try this instead.

```
SELECT
    a.x_code, b.item_id, c.action_type, b.item_name
FROM
    B b
       JOIN
    A a ON b.item_id = a.item_id
        JOIN
    C c ON c.item_name = b.item_name
```

Note I changed the table order and put the join table first.

If you insist on outer joins, change the joins to LEFT OUTER JOIN - both of them, and add a WHERE a.x_code IS NOT NULL AND c.action_type IS NOT NULL to the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample query.

**Example:**
**3 tables (product,category,subcategory)**
**product:** product_id, product_name, cat_id
**category:** cat_id, cat_name
**subcategory:** subcat_id, subcat_name, cat_id

```
SELECT product.product_name, category.cat_name, subcategory.subcat_name
FROM product
INNER JOIN category ON product.cat_id = category.cat_id
INNER JOIN subcategory ON category.cat_id=subcategory.cat_id;
```

Comment: No luck using INNER JOIN either. The connection times out

Answer (score 0):

Try having non-clustered index set on columns used in join clause

In this case the columns should be

1. **item_id** in table b (include **item_name** to this index)
2. **item_id** in table a (include **x_code** to this index)
3. **item_name** in table c (include **action_type** to this index)

This would force the query optimizer to use the index seek avoiding the full table scans.

Having the columns used in select clause to include in index would save many unnecessary page(memory) access, since the data that the query needs can be found in index itself.

In many cases, outer join does not use indexes, try using index hint to force it to use index.

**Note**: It is recommended to avoid setting index on column with very less distinct values or with large number chars in it.

Comment: Hey, that's what I've been using. Maybe I'm missing something. Could you please show it in an example with the JOIN clause? Thanks!

Comment: Though I work with SQL server, I believe most of these concepts are same. Try to get the query execution plan for your query, identify what Indexes your query is using. You might need to refer this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-performance-explain.html

Comment: Also, get the IO statistics (page accesses) using **SHOW PROFILE** (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profile.html). Then try decreasing the page access counts by optimizing the query.